# Correct way to delete all comments that belong to an image after the image is deleted?

Tags: php, laravel

I can think of two ways to do that:

The first one is to add code to the `deleteImage()` function which finds all comments that belonged to that image and then delete them as well.

And the second one is create a foreign key and use `onDelete('cascade');` so that when the image is deleted, all comments that belonged to it would get deleted as well.

At the end, both ways accomplish the same thing, however, there might be pros/cons to each way that I might not be aware of and that is why I'm asking you guys. Any input would be apppreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really up to you, just document it in a good place.

The `deleteImage()` is obvious but can be easily forgotten. The cascade is less obvious but one might not expect to delete comments from the database if they delete an image file. There is no right or wrong, just make sure to document it somewhere and be consistent.

Comment: Is one of those 2 methods more popular?

Comment: I really wouldn't know. I prefer cascades because I refactor my code a lot and I'm bound to forget a manual function call. But again, it really is up to you.